# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY ubuntu 14.04 cuda8

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, ubuntu-14.04

I am using tensorflow with cuda8 on ubuntu 14.04
My CPU: GeForce GT 740M
I am a newbie to GPUs
Sometimes, after I have run the same script several times on the gpu, I will get a memory error, which will be gone the next time I reboot.
Thanks for sharing your expertise with me. I dont really know how to solve this problem.

Here is the error message:

```
        I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910]
        successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value   (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node  zero
        I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885]                 
        Found device 0 with properties: 
        name: GeForce GT 740M
        major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0325
        pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
        Total memory: 1.96GiB
        Free memory: 118.75MiB
        I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
        I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
        I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975]          
        Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
        E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1002] failed to allocate 118.75M (124518400 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
        E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:397] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
        E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:364] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
        F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:605] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms) 
        Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Well, without seeing your code, it's impossible; to be sure but it sounds like you're not freeing resources, resulting in a memory leak (another alternative is memory gragmentatyion). These are always a pain to locate and doing it on a GPU just makes things more interesting. You're going to either need to track all memory allocations and ensure they're tidied up or you're going to have to remove chunks of code until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons you could be getting this issue.

- Check if you're using the GPU to also run X server because it crashed from the start.  Check with nvidia-smi to see how much space you actually have to work with.
- Make sure you have the appropriate CUDA drivers and toolkit version for the tensorflow you are running (367.35 or newer and toolkit 8.0)
- Is your card supported? (I think it should work but nvidia likes to be sneaky about supporting old hardware where they lock you out as a way to buy newer nvidia GPUs). After double checking your card is supported. Needs CUDA compute >= 3.0
- You can debug your code with the tensorflow debugger.
- Last but not least as comments have suggested it seems like your GPU resources aren't being freed after your software has ended.  Make sure you kill the process as the GPU will free the resources after the program calls exit().